# Working with more than one designer

Tags: website-design, designers, client-relations

One of my clients is looking to re-design his website. As a project manager, I was assigned to this task. I found two designers that made a really good impression, and I consider hiring them both for doing the wireframing and the design.

What is the best way to do this without having them step on each other toes? I obviously wish to maximize the results I'm getting from them and make the collaboration bear fruits.

Answer (score 1):

I think, wire-framing should take place before designing. In that case you might finish wire-framing with a one guy & then design with other guy.